# How do I anchor a part in Roblox Studio without anchoring it?

Tags: lua, roblox

I made a small test boat for my tower defense game and I need the turret to rotate but not the rest of the boat and I can't anchor the boat because of network ownership. If I try welding or adding joints to the boat (non turret part) it rotates the whole boat. Without welds the boat teleports to where it was before I put it in replicated storage (but not the turret). I used a humanoid to rotate the turret to make it a bit easier to setup. So how do I make sure the boat base is placed in the chosen spot and only the turret rotates? [The Boat Base spawns in one spot but not the turret.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbE4O.png)       [The joints and everything in the whole boat tower.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3ECp.png)

```
local allowedToSpawn = tower.CheckSpawn(player, name)

if allowedToSpawn then
    
    local newTower = ReplicatedStorage.Towers[name]:Clone()
    newTower.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = cframe
    newTower.Parent = workspace.Towers
    newTower.HumanoidRootPart:SetNetworkOwner(nil)
    
    local bodyGyro = Instance.new("BodyGyro")
    bodyGyro.MaxTorque = Vector3.new(math.huge, math.huge, math.huge)
    bodyGyro.D = 0
    bodyGyro.CFrame = newTower.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame
    bodyGyro.Parent = newTower.HumanoidRootPart

    for i, object in ipairs(newTower:GetDescendants()) do 
        if object:IsA("BasePart") then
            PhysicsService:SetPartCollisionGroup(object, "Towers")  
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the position of the turret to the boats position and give it a offset

```lua
local boat = the boat
local turret = the turret

while wait() do
turret.Position = boat.Position + Vector3.new(1,1,1) --the offset
end
```

If you didnt mean it like this then I have no idea what you want